# How i can cast a WNDPROC to a TWndMethod

Tags: delphi, winapi

How i can cast  a `WNDPROC` to a [TWndMethod](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TWndMethod)

so far i try this but give me a `invalid typecast` error.

```
 TWndMethod(Pointer(GetWindowLong(FHandle, GWL_WNDPROC)));
```

Comment: You are implementing ancient window subclassing technique in Delphi. Generally it is not as easy as Sertac Akyuz answer (and requires more details about what are you doing for a good answer - may be your don't need this kind of subclassing at all), but an answer to your current question is MakeObjectInstance function.

Comment: Back up. What makes you think you need to do such a thing at all? You're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to subclass a window handle (using SetWindowLong) to process window messages in TWndMethod function, you should not cast the value returned by GetWindowLong(FHandle, GWL_WNDPROC) to TWndMethod. You should use MakeObjectInstance function to obtain a value that can be passed to SetWindowLong instead. Read Sertac Akuyz answer for a general idea.

Note that the need to subclass a window handle is very rare in Delphi applications. Delphi provides several other ways to interfere into window message processing, they are more simple and safe.

Comment: Since the mentioned answer is no more, one can check the second code example in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660799/why-doesnt-my-cursor-change-to-an-hourglass-in-my-finddialog-in-delphi/2661080#2661080) to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660799/why-doesnt-my-cursor-change-to-an-hourglass-in-my-finddialog-in-delphi) to see sub-classing at work for a good cause.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems here.  First, GetWindowLong doesn't give you the actual WndProc, but a handle to it.

Second, TWndMethod is defined as `procedure(var Message: TMessage) of object;`  It's a method pointer, not a function pointer, so you can't cast a normal pointer to it.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Mason, i want to get the `WndProc` from a window handle to process the messages using a callback function of  type  `TWndMethod`

Comment: MakeObjectInstance() is the way to go for that.